# Sending JSON object. How do I set up the simple .net controller method to receive this type?

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, json, angular

Currently I am sending over object from angular that looks exactly like this.

{"department":2,"note":"asdf","weekEnding":"2019-11-02T00:00:00"}

I am then hitting this method in my my .net controller which looks like this.

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("Edit")]
    public void Edit([FromForm] CorpNotes newMessage)
    {

        //_SLGContext.Entry(newMessage).State = EntityState.Modified;
        //_SLGContext.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Here is my model for CorpNotes below

```
public class CorpNotes
{
    public string Department { get; set; }

    public string Note { get; set; }

    public string WeekEnding { get; set; }
}
```

I am receiving all null values in the variable CorpNotes newMessage in my Post method Edit()

Why are all my values null?
**slg-corp-notes.service.ts**

```
  updateMessage(message: any) {
    console.log("at service")
    console.log(message)
    var newMessage = new CorpNotes(message['departments'], message['noteBody'], message['weeks'].weekEnding)
    var Params = '?Department=' + message['departments'] + '&Note=' + message['noteBody'] + '&WeekEnding=' + message['weeks'].weekEnding
    console.log(newMessage)
    console.log(JSON.stringify(newMessage))
    console.log(Params)

    const headers = new HttpHeaders()
      .set('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=UTF-8')

    let options = { headers: headers };

    return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + 'api/SlgCorpNotes/Edit', JSON.stringify(newMessage), options);
    //return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + 'api/SlgCorpNotes/Edit', JSON.stringify(newMessage))


  }
```

Comment: why you think that you can send JSON and it will be read as form data (FromForm)?

Comment: Because I had FormBody before and I would get a 415 error.  Once I switched to FormForm I then hit the method with no error

Comment: 415 is self-explanatory ...

Comment: So I should remove formform?

Comment: yes and point right media type by right header on client side

Comment: Let me show you what I have on client side header in my next edit

Comment: You can see I have the correct headers

Comment: yes , but you are prolly(i'm not into javascript/angular) sending a string instead json

Comment: Try removing the fromForm

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Values null when I make a simple post request to my .net controller from angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58630799/values-null-when-i-make-a-simple-post-request-to-my-net-controller-from-angular)

Comment: If I remove fromForm I'm back to a 415 error.  If I add fromForm then it takes me into the method.  If I have fromBody then it gives me 415 error too

Comment: No it doesn't answer my question.  That question used to be a 415 error.  Then there is no error by adding fromForm.  Editing the header or any of those suggestions didn't take the 415 error away.  I just guessed and put to fromForm, and then there was no 415 error

Comment: Any suggestions?  But back formBody then get a 415 error.  Add headers still 415 errors.  I'm lost please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. remove the `JSON.stringify` from your Angular `http.post` call. It should just be able to recognise an object.
2. Your last field in the JSON is a date but your C# model expects a string, change that to a date too.

Comment: Your right.  I took off stringify then I created a new object like this     var newMessage = {
      "Departments": message["departments"],
      "Note": message["noteBody"],
      "WeekEnding": message["weeks"].weekEnding
    }

Comment: I then passed newMessage return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + 'api/SlgCorpNotes/Edit',newMessage, options);

Comment: then the controller took in the object as such.         public void Edit([FromBody] CorpNotes newMessage)